# SQL Query for columns with a unique value

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a table which looks like this

```
    courseid     session_date     title                 published
    1            2012-07-01       Training Course A     0
    1            2012-07-02       Training Course A     0
    2            2012-07-04       Training Course B     1
    2            2012-07-07       Training Course B     1
    3            2012-07-05       Training Course C     1
    3            2012-07-06       Training Course C     1
    4            2012-07-07       Training Course D     1
    4            2012-07-10       Training Course D     1
```

The table has two entries for each ID and Title because the session_date column shows the start date and the end date of the course.

I am trying to create a query that will pull the next five courses without showing any courses in the past.

I have gotten this far

```
    SELECT session_date, title, courseid
    FROM table
    WHERE published = 1 AND session_date > DATE(NOW())
    ORDER BY session_date ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

This pulls rows from the table for the next five session-dates but it includes both start dates and finish dates whereas I need the next five courses ordered by start date.

I need to create a query that will pull the earliest session_date for each courseid but ignore the row with the latest session_date for that same courseid but I am at a complete loss of how to do this.

Any help or advice would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group your results by course and select the `MAX(session_date)`, you will get the latest of the dates associated with each course (i.e. the finish date):

```
SELECT   courseid, MIN(session_date) AS start_date
FROM     `table`
WHERE    published = 1
GROUP BY courseid
HAVING   start_date > CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY start_date ASC
LIMIT    5
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc5e3/6/0).

Comment: You're picking the wrong row... the OP states 'I need to create a query that will **pull the earliest** session_date for each courseid but **ignore the row with the latest** session_date'

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is retrieve only the rows with the minimum `session_date` per `courseid` group and order by that resulting set:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT courseid, MIN(session_date) AS mindate
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY courseid
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    tbl b ON a.courseid = b.courseid AND a.mindate = b.session_date
WHERE
    b.session_date > NOW() AND
    b.published = 1
ORDER BY
    b.session_date
LIMIT 5
```

But a much better design would be to only have one row per `courseid` and have two columns specifying start and end dates:

```
tbl
------------------
courseid [PK]
start_date
end_date
title
published
```

Then you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE start_date > NOW() AND published = 1
ORDER BY start_date
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Hi Zane,

Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate your time in helping me out. Your solution worked but I have used the solution above from eggyal as it was a bit lighter on code.

Answer (score 0):

Since values of all the columns in your SELECT clause are repeating, just use DISTINCT

`SELECT distinct session_date, title, courseid
    FROM table
    WHERE published = 1 AND session_date > DATE(NOW())
    ORDER BY session_date ASC LIMIT 0,5`

Comment: For each training course, there are two session dates (the start + the end date).  These will both be distinct rows, so using a distinct on the query won't actually reduce the number of rows returned.